# How do you become an expert in a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

Assuming you have basic to intermediate knowledge of a particular language, how can you become an expert in that language in a short amount of time?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this [21 Days](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) by Peter Norvig

Answer (score 2):

Pull all your information sources together - such as:

The official language documentation,
Best practice books,
Google around for tutorial sites,

Get used to searching and finding what you need quickly

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reply would be: Practice makes perfect. 
Try to work with the language on daily basis and push yourself out of your comfort zone in using it. Joining a user group is also a good option. 
But at the end of the day, I must agree with Rozuur and concede that becoming an expert in something usually requires experience and experience requires time.

Answer (score 1):

I think,

1. Passion: to explore and learn, and then
2. Dedication: to learn different aspects of that programming language, finally,
3. Patience: to design a project and apply all that one has learned into it.

Note:The programming languages these days have grown too big to implement above strategy.

However, I would still believe that passion is the key to all learning!